# Wireshark - Graphic analysis tool. anyone knows?

Tags: wireshark, analysis

Does anyone knows a graphical tool to analyse wireshark captures?

Like something that can agregate traffic by ip's and by protocol and show's it graphicly.

Anyone knows a freeware/opensource utility?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the spot, or have a more permanent statistics-gathering setup?

Comment: I want to save a pcap, and then analyse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried Wireshark's own "statistics" tools. You have some pretty nice tools to do endpoint conversation analysis (somehow similar to netflow), IO graphs, per protocol statistics, protocols hierarchies, flow graphs, packet length distributions plus several others. Also, many of these tools accepts Wireshark's filter syntaxis so the drill down you can make and the information you can extract from a pcap file is quite deep.

Comment: Thanks jliendo, i didn't saw that feature. That did it it's a very nice feature and it gives an idea of going overall.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently purchased [Cascade Pilot](http://www.riverbed.com/us/products/cascade/cascade_pilot.php), which is kind of spendy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the network device(s), you can do what you're asking with NetFlow if they support it. This may be a better fit (and lower overhead) than using Wireshark, depending on your needs and architecture. It's not the answer to your question, but it might be something you didn't know to ask for.

Comment: Does it work won Windows? (win2008r2 / Win7)

Comment: MRTG would also work, using a relatively simple SNMP setup instead of a possibly awkward Netflow configuration.

Comment: NetFlow is a protocol, like SNMP. You need to run Netflow collector software that is pointing at your network devices. There are netflow collectors that run on Windows, yes. SolarWinds Orion has a netflow component, there are others.

Comment: Hyppy- Can you actually get protocol-level information from SNMP? As requested, Flip wants IPs (doesn't specific source or destination) and protocol - presumably TCP/UDP port, again not specified but that's most common. How do you export or query that via SNMP? I didn't think you could, but if you know how, that would be great.

Comment: Ahh you're right, no protocol information in SNMP that I know of, at least not without getting really dirty in the MIBs on a vendor-by-vendor basis :-/

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting PCAP graphing into a Circos format can be done with IPLink, available for free at [http://ip-link.wikidot.com](http://ip-link.wikidot.com/). You'll need to install a Python interpreter and Perl.

A very manual method using tcptrace and xplot is outlined on the following blog, which may be more along the lines of what you're looking for: http://geek00l.blogspot.com/2005/11/visualize-network-traffic.html